# How to transition from home grown authentication solution to using canned OpenID Identity Provider

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, keycloak, saml-2.0

We have a home-grown authentication and authorization solution and we would like to transition to a canned Identity Provider, such as Keycloak, for example.  Is there any documentation and or media that discuss the best approaches for integrating an Identify Provider, such as Keycloak, for example, such an environment, with existing users and passwords, etc?  Thanks in advance for any help and/or direction you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit broad but I can address one of the areas I've done in the past.  I converted a solution that had clear text passwords stored in a database (!) to use Keycloak.  The clear text passwords made it simple to create new users.  I used a role based environment and, after creating the realm I created the roles and users using the `kcadm.sh` command line.  My script looked something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8180/auth --realm master --user admin --password the-admin-password

kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=therealm -s enabled=true -o

kcadm.sh create roles -r therealm -s name=employee -s 'description=Role to that is used by employees'

kcadm.sh create users -r therealm -s username=somebody@domain.tld -s email=somebody@domain.tld -s lastName=Body -s firstName=Some -s 'credentia
ls=[{"type":"password", "value": "the-user-password"}]' -s 'enabled=true' -s 'emailVerified=true'    

kcadm.sh add-roles --uusername somebody@domain.tld --rolename employee -r therealm
```

This allowed me to create the base set of users.  These users were in the "local" database, not a third party like Google or Microsoft.  Of course, if you don't have the user passwords you could create a script that generates a temporary password and email that to the users.  Then you'd want to setup users to force a password change.

This conversion was a set of JAX-RS web services in a Java webapp and ended up using a custom `ContainerRequestFilter` that allowed me to pull the JWT out and create a custom `Principal` for the user.  I'm sure a "normal" servlet filter could be used too.

Answer (score 0):

It imay be reasonable also for you to ask all users to create a new password - since this will only occur once per user - if this works for you my post may help you to understand options:

https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/